# How to make Touch Painting work in Krita?

Tags: touchscreen, 18.10, krita

I have a convertible laptop with touchscreen (Dell Inspiron 13", about 2 years old). Touch works flawlessly in the whole system, I can even draw notes in Google Keep in Chrome, but I cannot draw in Krita.

I tried toggling the `Enable Touch Painting` in settings, it didn't help. All the search results about this issue are ancient, dating back to at least 2016... I'm not sure even in which direction to look.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue on a Toshiba convertable. The only references i found so far are this discurrsion in the forum https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=133723 and the "Enable Touchpainting" section from the official documentation over here https://docs.krita.org/en/reference_manual/preferences/general_settings.html Looking at the settings i'd suppose it's supposed to work. Which it does not seem to do

Answer (score 0):

I 'fixed' this problem by using the snap (currently version 4.2.x) whereas the apt version (4.1.x) did not work on my Inspiron.